# merge/remove elements from a ManyToMany relationship (using through table) when saving model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm developping an app to manage commands for a restaurant.
as the commands can evolve through the diner, for more clarity, I want to merge the command's lines that contain the same product. For instance, if you command 2 buckets of chicken, then later another one, I want the final Command model instance to contain only one line (bucket of chicken, 3) instead of two.

I have a function (fusion_atoms) which detects similar lines and merge them. I tried to call it in the save method of Command model, and also during pre_save and post_save signals. It doesn't work.
I'm quite a noob in python and django, and I think I'm not doing this the right way.

models.py:

```
class Command_Atom(models.Model):
    command = models.ForeignKey("Command", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    produit = models.ForeignKey(Produit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantite = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)
    @property
    def total(self):
        return self.produit.prix * self.quantite

class Command (models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    table = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    produits = models.ManyToManyField(Produit, through="Command_Atom")

    @property
    def atoms(self):
        return Command_Atom.objects.filter(command_id=self.id)

    def fusion_atoms(self):
        lines = self.atoms.all().order_by('produit','prod_options')
        i = 1
        current_line = lines[0]
        to_be_deleted = []
        while i < len(lines):
            if current_line.produit == lines[i].produit:
                print('merge')
                current_line.quantite += lines[i].quantite
                current_line.save()
                to_be_deleted.append(lines[i])
            else:
                current_line = lines[i]
            i += 1
        for l in to_be_deleted:
            l.delete()

    def save(self):
        self.fusion_atoms()
        super(Command,self).save()
```

signals.py:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Command_atom)
def presave_atom(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs['instance']
    print("pre_save %s" % instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Command_Atom)
def postsave_Command(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs['instance']
    print("post_save %s" % instance)

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Command)
def presave_note(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs['instance']
    #instance.fusion_atoms()
    print("pre_save %s" % instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Command)
def postsave_note(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs['instance']
    #instance.fusion_atoms()
    print("post_save %s" % instance)
```

I found that the problem is that pre_save and post_save methods of the Command model are executed BEFORE the objects of the manytomanyfield are actualy saved/updated, so that even if the fusion_atom method does its job, firstly it operates on values that have not been updated yet, (because the lines of the Command are updated AFTER the Command has been saved) and secondly, these changes are reverted when the atoms are saved.

In other words, something happens during the process, but the final result is that nothing has changed :-)

Why the post_save signal is called BEFORE all its field are saved ? This seems quite inconsistent (with all respect due to that wonderfull tool)

Is there a way to call the fusion method at the end of the whole process of saving ? 
A signal to know when the elements of the M2M field have all been saved ?

Or is there a complete other approach ?

Comment: Try trapping the M2M signal. The M2M table will be updated after the primary object is sorted. @receiver(models.signals.m2m_changed, ..)